# Passing PSCustomObject parameter as input to function defined in different module

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In this script, I am trying to pass `$config, $inputData, $environment` to my function named `Authenticate` defined in module `Methods.psm1`. However upon debugging, it seems like these parameters passed are not available. Not sure I am missing here.

Script 1: CustomScript.ps1

```
Import-Module -Name .\Methods.psm1 -Verbose
$config = Get-Content .\configuration.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$inputData = Get-Content .\registration.json | ConvertFrom-Json;
$environment = $config.environments.test; # Set this value to change environment

Write-Host "Loaded Configurations..."
<#--------------------------- Authentication request------------------------------------#>
#-Headers @{"accept"="text/psv"}
$r = Authenticate -config $config -inputData $inputData  -environment $environment;
```

Script 2: Methods.psm1

```
function Authenticate {
param ([Parameter(Mandatory)][PSCustomObject]$config
        ,[Parameter(Mandatory)][PSCustomObject]$inputData
        ,[Parameter(Mandatory)][PSCustomObject]$environment
        )      
    $e = $environment;
    $i = $inputData;
    $c = $config   
}
```

Comment: There are no problems with the code you posted. I replicated your setup with dummy data, and all the data is available in the Authenticate function. I notice you are assigning the result of Authenticate to `$r`, but you are not returning anything in the function.

Comment: Here when I check $e or $i or $c for any values. It shows me blank string however upon setting watch on all these variables along with $environment and others, I can see the value in $environment and other variables. So I am not sure what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Try adding (above the call to Authenticate) `$config | Out-Host` and then inside the `Authenticate` function the same; `$config | Out-Host`. When I tried, these both output the data. Are you by any chance using ISE? If so, that might be the problem.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Are you trying to inspect the value of `$e`, `$i` and `$c` _after_ `Authenticate` runs? They only exist in the local function scope, so they won't have a value outside the function after the fact.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am trying to inspect these by setting breakpoint as well as tried using Write-Host. But in both cases value being printed is blank.
@Cbsch I am using VSCode and all files are in same folder location. I will check this `$config | Out-Host `